# Can't start a web browser (Firefox Snap) with VNC

Tags: xfce, vnc, xrdp

I did steps 1 and 2 from [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-22-04) and was able to connect from a remote host with UltraVNC, but was unable to run a browser:

[image]

Tried to install FireFox:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

but it did not help.

VNC config (xstartup):

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

Ubuntu version: 22.04 server.

I run VNC server by executing the following command:

```
vncserver -geometry 1400x850 $@
```

FireFox also does not start from the menu:

[image]

(nothing happens when I click on the menu item)

When I run it from the terminal I get this:

[image]

XFCE version:

[image]

Comment: Seems like an issue with the snap version. Install the APT package https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/124466

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I installed firefox from a wrong repository, right?

Comment: By default, Ubuntu installs firefox from snap (even if you install it using APT). While it is convenient for Canonical to maintain the snap version, it has a lot of bugs (the one you are facing is also probably another snap bug). The workaround is to use the APT version maintained by Mozilla, from the PPA. How to do it is mentioned in the link I had posted.